# Apache RedirectMatch Regular Expression

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get an Apache redirect to work properly. Here is the rule I have written:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/signup.php\?price_group\[\](.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/pricing/
```

Which should match a url like:

```
/signup.php?price_group[]anthing-else-here
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) manual page:

> mod_alias is designed to handle simple URL manipulation tasks. For
>   more complicated tasks such as manipulating the query string, use the
>   tools provided by mod_rewrite.

Using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) you would write:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^price_group\[\]
RewriteRule ^signup\.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/pricing/? [R=302,L]
```

- These lines should go in the `.htaccess` file present in the root directory of your website
- Change 302 to 301 when you are done testing.

Comment: That worked, but it passes along the rest of the query string into /pricing/. How do I just clear the query string.

Comment: Not sure, try adding a `?` at the end. I think it should clear the query string; I also think a `?` on its own will not be added in the redirected URL.